# How to extract all words starting with specific character from string in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, regex, string, postgresql

I am trying to extract all words that start from 'M' character.

For example I have a string:
"[{"name": "Mary", "type": "Dog"}, {"name": "Max", "type": "Dog"}]"
I want to get: "Mary, Max"

I tried to regex_replace([{"name": "Mary", "type": "Dog"}, {"name": "Max", "type": "Dog"}], '\W', '', 'g') and left only words, but don't know the correct regex to extract all words starting with 'M'. I also tried this: substring("name Mary type Dog name Max type Dog" from '\w*M\w*') but this gives me only one word.

Comment: [This](https://dbfiddle.uk/CaIfmzOD) seems to work, but if you wait, there will probably be smarter ideas :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT array_to_string(
REGEXP_MATCHES(
    '[{"name": "Mary", "type": "Dog"}, {"name": "Max", "type": "Dog"}]',
    '\mM\w+\M',
    'g'
  ),
  ', '
) AS result;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following pattern.

```
:\s+"(?=M)(.+?)"
```

Output for group 1.

```
Mary
Max
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Postgresql's **regexp_matches** function. Documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-matching.html).

This query might help.

```
SELECT array_to_string(regexp_matches(
    '[{"name": "Mary", "type": "Dog"}, {"name": "Max", "type": "Dog"}]',
    '"name": "M\w+"',
    'g'
), ', ') AS words;
```

It returns a comma separated string. The 'g' flag specifies that all results must be returned.

One other way to get the same result is via **LIKE** operator.

```
SELECT string_agg(value, ', ') AS words
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(
    '[{"name": "Mary", "type": "Dog"}, {"name": "Max", "type": "Dog"}]'
) AS elem
WHERE value LIKE 'M%'
```